# Pull to refresh issue in infiniteContainer

Tags: codenameone

Pull to refresh gives different datas (not starting from the initial data) since the pageNumber in the following code increases. How can I set the value of pageNumber int to zero when pull to refresh is called in infiniteContainer?

```
InfiniteContainer ic = new InfiniteContainer() {
    @Override
    public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = fetchHerbData(res);
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    }
};

int pageNumber = 0;

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> fetchHerbData(Resources res) {
    try {
    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
        r.setPost(false);
        r.setUrl("http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api");
        r.addArgument("pretty", "0");
        r.addArgument("action", "search_listings");
        r.addArgument("encoding", "json");
        r.addArgument("listing_type", "buy");
        r.addArgument("page", "" + pageNumber);
        pageNumber++;
        r.addArgument("country", "uk");
        r.addArgument("place_name", text);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
        Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
        Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)result.get("response");
        return (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>)response.get("listings");
    } catch(Exception err) {
        Log.e(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
    if(index == 0) pageNumber = 0;
    //... rest of code
}
```